# MessageDialog flow direction not getting reflected in WP8.1 Universal app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I am just developing a Universal windows application with Bidirectional language support. I added Arab language and changed the flow direction of root frame in App.xaml.cs. Its working fine in Win8.1 but the flow direction of MessageDialog is always LefttoRight, its not changing only in WP8.1. Did any one faced this issue?

apart from MessageDialog, all seems to be fine.. please help....

Comment: Did any one know the answer to this question? please help me....

Answer (score 0):

It seems, it is not possible to access FlowDirection in built-in MessageDialog provided by Winrt as, MessageDialog is not inherited or part of FrameworkElement. In order to achieve this, may be you can try some custom dialog control and toggle its visibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vishal. But the flow direction is automatically changing in Win8.1 but not in phone. This is really makes me crazy...  What could be the reason its not working in phone elone?? any idea??

Comment: Built-in Message box does not support as discussed. May be, you can try CustomMessageBox in the Windows Phone Toolkit, but I don't think they will provide it either as it just simulates the native message box and only allows to change the contents. I think, it'd be better to create a custom control :)